# C# Interfaces rules of thumb for data types returned

Tags: c#, interface

I am developing an application in C# that is basically an interface that can take or return data to a variety of outside applications/clients through (most likely) a REST API. The application should be designed flexibly enough that the back-end data store can be swapped out with only a config file change to point to a new data store or possibly cycle through available data stores to find data on differently formatted data stores. The overall structure of the data is roughly a file system/tree with custom data attached to some of the nodes for search, permissions...etc.

For example, we could possible have live production data in a SQL DB but there's a chance that some legacy data would be stored in flattened csv files on a network share, and there is a desire for new implementations of the interface to be included in the future (the database implementation of these would already have been defined, meaning if something has a pkid of type GUID we can't change that.)

The issue that I'm having in planning this is that these back-end data formats have different unique ids...etc. So the interface might have a method of:

```
public long CreateFolder(long parent, string folderName);
```

Which would work fine for something using integer or long Ids, but the consumer of the interface implementation would have issues if the return of a CreateFolder action was a guid or filename (string). The desire is also to change the 'business logic' layer as little as possible and make changes at the lowest level data layer.

My first thought was to create all of the interfaces returning strings and let the data layer implementations deal with casting strings to the native data type, but that seems ugly to me.

Any guidance on something like this?

EDIT: To add this is the pattern that I'm using for the DB interfaces.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/301362/how-are-abstract-database-interfaces-written-to-support-multiple-database-types/301371

Right now I'm leaning towards overloading all interfaces with string, int and long then handling the casting/conversion in the interface implementation.

Comment: `interface foo
    {
        T3 CreateFolder<T1, T2, T3>(T1 parent, T2 folder);
    }`

Comment: This doesn't really get me any closer, I should have mentioned that one of the back-end data stores use WSDL interfaces which are strongly typed. So it's not pure query code. So now I would have code like: `parent = long.Parse(parent.ToString())`

Answer (score 0):

You need to abstract out the differences. At its simplest, change the signature to:

`public IFolder CreateFolder(long parent, string folderName);`

Define IFolder as a C# interface like this:

`public interface IFolder
{
    // Example method to be implemented by inheritors.
    void EnumerateFiles();
}`

Each back-end data format will need its own concrete class that inherits and implements IFolder. The CreateFolder caller does know which concrete back-end class it is talking too, as it only sees the abstract IFolder interface.

Comment: I think this is basically the way that I was going, but then the business logic one layer above which utilizes the interface implementations still could have conflicts with the data types coming back unless I'm missing something. As in folder.id sometimes need to be a long and sometimes a string.

Answer (score 0):

Requirements:

1. Have an option to store/get data in different sources
2. Easy to change connection what to use.

Solution:

I think in your case will be good to use Repository pattern and some Fabric who decided which repository to use. Also, you can create repository as a generic to have an option fast to change for which model to work.

```
public class IRepository<T> where T : class
{
   T Save(T model);
   IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression... condition);
   //another methods.
}

DbRepository<T> :IRepository<T>
{
}
CsvRepository<T> :IRepository<T>
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose you a possible solution:

```
public abstract class AbstractController<T> : ApiController {
    [HttpPost] // Or GET
    [Route("createfolder")]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateFolder<T>(long parent, string foldername) {
        T result = YourClass.CreateFolder<T>(parent, foldername);

        return Ok(result);
    }
}

[RoutePrefix("api/sql")]
public abstract class SqlController : AbstractController<long> { }

[RoutePrefix("api/csv")]
public abstract class SqlController : AbstractController<string> { }
```

Is this a possible way?